# Live video in colab

Tags: video-streaming, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to run a live video in colab for Object detection? or How do i connect CCTV camera dvr/Nvr in Google Colab for Object detection?

I am unable to get video feed (rtsp stream) from Google colab.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We cannot help you with your question currently. What did you try so far? Try to give us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Furthermore, I invite you to read this link to improve your question(s) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of live camera capture in Colab's bundled code snippets: see https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi. Depending on what you would like to do with the stream, you may be able to use a similar approach.

Comment: Is there any way that the webcam will continue to capture and give it? I am trying to do a project on mask detection. In this project, I want to get the result in the continuous video that if there is a mask or not. here I see that I need to capture then get the image. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608972/mask-detection-project-using-local-camera-in-google-colab-want-to-do-on-live .Thanks in advance :)